# How to access Android device remotely from desktop

Tags: android, google-play

I want to access Android devices(Motorola Xoom) remotely from desktop.How i can access and control the device from desktop?Please help me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "access" and "control"?

Comment: for example we are accessing one desktop from another desktop like that

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible only with rooted devices.
Look at this http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/
or this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webkey

Comment: Great comment. There are multiple apps that work by now for remote access of an android device. Screencast has horrible instructions and it seems you need the device physically connected to the PC with adb-server running to access it.